# Naive Bayes implementation

Tags: r, naivebayes

In my project, I used naive bayes implementation from "e1071" library and time execution was fairly large. Then, I used the naive bayes implementation from "nblearn", and the results were very similar but the execution time was sometimes nearly 10 times smaller!

Has anyone noticed the same? What can be the reason for that?

```
testNaiveBayes <-function(formula, trainingData, testData)
{
    model <- naiveBayes(formula, trainingData)
    pred <- predict(model, testData)
    result <- calcRatesFor(formula, testData, pred ) 
    result
}

testNB <-function(formula, trainingData, testData)
{
    cl <- toString(formula[[2]])
    model <- naive.bayes(trainingData, cl)
    pred <- predict(model, testData)
    result <- calcRatesFor(formula, testData, pred ) 
    result
}
```

Comment: Not an expert but the 2 implementations differ. `e1071` implementation seems to be the classical implementation of the statistical calculation of Naive Bayes while the `bnlearn` is said to predict with naive Bayes and Tree-Augmented naive Bayes (TAN) classifiers. See link here: http://www.bnlearn.com/documentation/man/naive.bayes.html